# Cannot access user_data when using job queue

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a function that I need to be able to both execute by sending a command and execute automatically using a [job queue](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html). And in that function I need to have access to `user_data` to store data that is specific to each user. Now the problem is that when I try to execute it via job queue, `user_data` is `None` and thus unavailable. How can I fix that?

Here's how I'm currently doing this, simplified:

```py
import datetime
from settings import TEST_TOKEN, BACKUP_USER
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from pytz import timezone


def job_daily(context: CallbackContext):
    job(BACKUP_USER, context)


def job_command(update, context):
    job(update.message.chat_id, context)


def job(chat_id, context):
    print(context.user_data)


def main():
    updater = Updater(TEST_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    job_queue = updater.job_queue

    # To run it automatically
    tehran = timezone("Asia/Tehran")
    due = datetime.time(15, 3, tzinfo=tehran)
    job_queue.run_daily(job_daily, due)

    # To run it via command
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("job", job_command))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now when I send the command `/job` and thus executing `job_command`, the `job` function prints `{}` which means that I can access `user_data`. But when the `job_daily` function is executed, the `job` function prints `None` meaning that I don't have access to `user_data`. Same goes for `chat_data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a callback function of `python-telegram-bot`, `context.user_data` and `context.chat_data` depend on the `update`. More precisely, PTB takes `update.effective_user/chat.id` and provides the corresponding `user/chat_data`. Jobs callbacks are not triggered by an `update` (but by a time based trigger), so there's no reasonable way to provide `context.user_data`.

What you *can* do, when scheduling the job from within a handler callback, where `user_data` is available, is to pass it as `context` argument to the job:

```
context.job_queue.run_*(..., context=context.user_data)
```

Then within the job callback, you can retrieve it as `user_data = context.job.context`

In your case, you schedule the job in `main`, which is not a handler callback and hence you don't have `context.user_data` (not even `context`). If you have a specific user id for which you'd like to pass the `user_data`, you can get that `user_data` as `user_data = updater.dispatcher.user_data[user_id]`, which is the same object as `context.user_data` (for updates from this particular user).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks.